# Rib Roast Rare standing up or lying down?

Tags: roast-beef

I have a 4 inch thick one which I'd like rare. Will it make a difference if I cook it standing up or flat in the pan? And at what temperature? I have an electric oven.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ribs as a roasting rack. In the spirit of the day, I will share with you my favorite [*technique*](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/michael-symon/prime-rib-recipe.html). For rare, rare, cook to 120F (49C), that will carry over to 125F (52C).